# After deploying django in AWS EB its not working similarly as it runs in localhost

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[This is how Admin page works in local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYMZm.png)

[This is how its showing after deploying in AWS EB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhtYA.png)

can i get help on this like how to get it normal or how to modify it using my own templates please .

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before deploying run : `python manage.py collectstatic`

After running this you should deploy again like you usually do.

Answer (score 1):

In development django itself serves the files, which is not scalable in production, and thus requires you to `collect` your static files as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/) and serve them using your proxy server.

You can read about how collect static files in django on Elasticbeanstalk [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/#static-files)